# Winstore 8.1 app: performance test fails

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I am updating my windows 8.1 applications with package name "actysystemindiapvt. Ltd. ActySystemNorthwindJapanese"

But WACK fails the test while creating package and gives the error that the application package name is too long. However, I have already uploaded the previous version of the application with the same package name.

If I give a shorter name to the application, but at the time of associating application the package name automatically changes to the previous long package name. And in test result WACK fails the test and shows an error message that application name is too long.

Here I am sharing screenshots of my steps, please take a moment to review it. 
**[Screenshots](http://1drv.ms/1pCRHpN)**

(Since this forum does not allow more than 2 images per message so I am sharing these via skydrive sorry for the trouble)

Note: I am using VS2013 and WACK 3.2

Thanks & regards,

Rudresh Bhatt